# Need some unit testing checklists

Tags: automated-testing

I am looking for some good checklists / point regarding units tests. Could anyone please give some good unit testing checklists?
I just need sample checklists as we are in the process of creating one common unit testing checklist across different projects in our company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [this](http://qtp.blogspot.com/2012/12/unit-testing-checklists.html) if it helps.